# Deleting from binary file

Tags: java, file

In Java, how can I delete content from a binary file? Do I need to copy everything excluding the removed portion in a temporary file and rename it as existing file?

Comment: Why do you think that if you delete content from binary file, you will not corrupt it?

Answer (score 3):

You can't delete part of a file directly on the disk. Copy the file contents excluding the portion to be deleted to a temporary file. Now delete the original file and rename the temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

You could just overwrite with 0's if the format doesn't mater, otherwise you will have to create a new file and replace the original. This would be the same for any language

Comment: Overwriting with zeroes is not the same as deleting.

Comment: It all depends on how paranoid/sure you need to be the data is gone.

Overwriting a section of a file with 0s probably stands more chance of removing the data from the disk than any of the other methods, since it will just update the sectors on disk.

Creating a new file and replacing the original is likely to leave the original files content on the disk unliked and the file name pointing at the new version.

Comment: You always need to create a new file containing the old data, minus the "deleted" part. Whether or not you zero-ise the previous file contents is a separate matter. Your answer doesn't currently explain that.